# Override ItemController in Custom Module in Orchard

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

**What do I want?**

I'm trying to override the Display method of the ItemController (Orchard.Core.Contents.Controllers.ItemController), so I can change the output based on the Accept Header.

1. If the header is "application/xml" I want to return xml
2. If the header is "application/json" I want to return json
3. Else return html ( like the default Display method)

**What have I done?**

I've made a copy of the ItemController  and have placed it in the Controller folder of my custom Module. Also added the OrchardSuppressDependency Attribute above the class.

```
[OrchardSuppressDependency("Orchard.Core.Contents.Controllers.ItemController")]
[Themed]
public class ItemController : Controller
{
    private readonly IContentManager _contentManager;

    public ItemController(IContentManager contentManager, IShapeFactory shapeFactory, IOrchardServices services)
    {
        _contentManager = contentManager;
        Shape = shapeFactory;
        Services = services;
        T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
    }

    dynamic Shape { get; set; }
    public IOrchardServices Services { get; private set; }
    public Localizer T { get; set; }

    // /Contents/Item/Display/72
    public ActionResult Display(int id)
    {
        var contentItem = _contentManager.Get(id, VersionOptions.Published);

        if (contentItem == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        if (!Services.Authorizer.Authorize(Permissions.ViewContent, contentItem, T("Cannot view content")))
        {
            return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
        //@Todo change output
        dynamic model = _contentManager.BuildDisplay(contentItem);
        return View((object)model);

    }
```

**Result**

An error is thrown in ShellRoute.cs Displaying

```
{"The controller for path '/OrchardLocal/products/product-2' was not found or does not implement IController."}
```

StackTrace

```
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
at Orchard.Mvc.OrchardControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) in XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\src\Orchard\Mvc\OrchardControllerFactory.cs:line 76
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
at Orchard.Mvc.Routes.ShellRoute.HttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) in XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\src\Orchard\Mvc\Routes\ShellRoute.cs:line 148
```

Have I overlooked something?
Or is this the wrong approach?

Comment: I think it's an exceptionally wrong approach ;) Why don't you simply create your own controller? Otherwise, a filter would be a lot easier.

Comment: You will need to overwrite the routes for this controller, not use SuppressDependency. I tried doing this a long time ago with no success. And I'd agree with Bertrand, there are other ways to do what you want :)

Comment: I've created a controller (copy of ItemController, but different name) inside my custom Module.
In Routes.cs I added a new RouteDescriptor referring to my custom Controller with a Priority of 15. Unfortunately the controller isn't reached. Only the ItemController is reached.

Comment: When I set the priority to a high number like 100, the constructor of my controller is reached. But after leaving the constructor (F10)  a source not found message ***ConstructorParameterBinding.cs is not found*** is shown in my Visual Studio.